# Can an author do book promotion on B1/B2 visa in USA?

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

Is an author permitted to stop by a few indie bookshops while doing a road trip in the USA to promote the author's self-published book? Would that be considered being paid by a USA entity?

It seems like a grey area. What if the author wasn't paid but their rep was. Would that work?

Comment: can you clarify whether you would be doing the road trip anyway, perhaps for tourism, and wonder about adding some bookstores to the itinerary, or whether the book tour is the purpose of the road trip?

Comment: If you're being paid by a book store in the US, then you are being paid by a US entity. Since you haven't specified whether the stores would be paying you, I've voted to close as unclear.

Comment: Are you being paid specifically for these appearances, or are you just doing it to promote your book?

Answer (score 5):

To me it sounds more like "Business" (which is allowed) than "Work" - **if** no-one is paying you by the hour to sit in the bookstore, or paying you an "appearance fee" or "honorarium". You're doing an activity that you hope will trigger revenue to some entity, but you're not collecting a salary.

A [US government blog](https://blogs.usembassy.gov/philippines/the-consequences-of-working-on-a-b1b2-visa-niv/) expands on the difference between work and business, and specifically lists permitted business activities:

> While on a B1/B2 (business/tourist) visa, you may engage in some business activities, including such things as a need to consult with business associates, negotiate a contract, buy goods or materials, settle an estate, appear in a court trial, or **participate in business or professional conventions or conferences**. You may also use a B1 visa when you will be traveling to the United States on behalf of a foreign employer for training or **meetings**.

[Bolding is mine.]

> However, you may not receive payment (except for incidental expenses) from a United States source while on a B1/B2 visa. Working at a job in the United States while on a B1/B2 visa is generally prohibited and is not an appropriate use of this visa class.

I have come into the US for no reason other than to visit my publisher, and showed the immigration officer my letter inviting me to the meeting, and I was allowed in. While this is not the same as a book tour, it's an indication that going to meetings is "business", not "work".

Also, I have come in to the US for the primary reason of "attending a conference" and at that conference I have signed books, sat on a panel about writing books, etc. I can hope that I got some royalties from that - I get literally a dollar or two when people buy a copy, and the bookstore people excitedly reported selling 5 or 6 copies on one occasion. But it wasn't work - the bookstore people didn't give me a dollar for each copy I signed. The panel people didn't give me (or anyone) a $500 appearance fee. Etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter whether payment is by the hour or not. Payment of a flat fee by a US entity is still payment by a US entity.

Comment: Sure, if they pay you for coming in and doing a thing, that's work. If you come in and do a thing (for no immediate money) in the hope that some entity somewhere will get more revenue, that's business. Especially if you get paid your salary at home regardless of whether you make this trip or not.

Comment: Agreed. The question seems to imply that there's an appearance fee, but it's far from clear.

Comment: @phoog and the alternative that payment be given to a 'rep' suggests that you're correct, it's business

Comment: I tend to agree, but I'm leery of "this makes sense to me" kind of answers where visas are concerned.

Comment: @DJClayworth added a ref, hope you like it

Comment: @KateGregory I do. +1.

Comment: Hello All,

It's my first time here, I'm not getting any notifications, sorry for the late clarifications. 

I will not be paid for any appearances, I am primarily going to see my partner's ailing grandma, his family and we decided to road trip since I haven't seen a lot of the USA. The books will be sold by the bookshop itself and I won't be paid for the appearance. It's more like a few stops by the bookshops across our way from east coast to west coast so I can promote the book and sign for whomever might want an autograph.

To clarify, I am bearing all the costs:)


Thanks!